# I.N. Herstein, "Topics in algebra" group theory section 2.8 example 2.8.1

Tags: group-theory

I.N. Herstein, "Topics in algebra" group theory section 2.8 example 2.8.1 it is written that

Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group of order $r$, $G=(a)$, $a^r=e$. Suppose $T$ is an automorphism of $G$. If $aT$ is known, since $a^iT=(aT)^i$, $a^iT$ is determined......

Can anyone explain me how $a^iT=(aT)^i$??

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is an automorphism, so $T(a^i)=T(a \cdot a \cdots a)=T(a)T(a) \cdots T(a)$ ($i$ times) = $T(a)^i$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Automorphisms are homomorphisms, so $(aT)(bT)=(ab)T$ for all $a, b\in G$.

If you want a formal proof, induct on $i$.